# Type or namespace could not be found 'Form1'

Tags: c#

I'm new to c#, and after looking through the other threads on this subject I'm still at a loss of how to fix the bug:C. 
I'm trying to make a simple calculator and here is the code for that:

```
   //Global Variables 
    string sign;
    double val1;
    double val2;

    int trackkeypoint = 0;

    public void Calculator()

    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    private void cmd0_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        txtbox.Text = txtbox.Text + cmd0.Text;
    }
    private void cmd1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        txtbox.Text=txtbox.Text+cmd1.Text;
    }
    private void cmd2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        txtbox.Text=txtbox.Text+cmd2.Text;
    }

    private void cmd3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        txtbox.Text=txtbox.Text+cmd3.Text;
    }

    private void cmd4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        txtbox.Text=txtbox.Text+cmd4.Text;
    }

    private void cmd5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        txtbox.Text=txtbox.Text+cmd5.Text;
    }

    private void cmd6_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        txtbox.Text=txtbox.Text+cmd6.Text;
    }

    private void cmd7_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        txtbox.Text=txtbox.Text+cmd7.Text;
    }

    private void cmd8_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        txtbox.Text=txtbox.Text+cmd8.Text;
    }

    private void cmd9_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        txtbox.Text=txtbox.Text+cmd9.Text;
    }
     private void cmdequal_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

         val2 = double.Parse(txtbox.Text);
         double result;

         if(sign=="+")
         {
             result = val1 + val2;
             txtbox.Text = result.ToString();

         }
         else if(sign=="-")
         {
             result = val1 - val2;
             txtbox.Text = result.ToString();
         }
         else if(sign=="X")
         {
             result = val1 * val2;
             txtbox.Text = result.ToString();
         }
         else if(sign=="/")
         {
             result = val1 / val2;
             txtbox.Text = result.ToString();

         }

    }


    private void cmdclear_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Clears text
        txtbox.Text = "";

        val1 = 0;

        val2 = 0;

        sign = "";

    }

    private void cmdplus_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        sign = "+";
        val1 = double.Parse(txtbox.Text);
        txtbox.Text = "";

    }

    private void cmdsubtract_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        sign = "-";
        val1 = double.Parse(txtbox.Text);
        txtbox.Text = "";
    }

    private void cmdmultiply_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        sign = "X";
        val1 = double.Parse(txtbox.Text);
        txtbox.Text = "";
    }

    private void cmddivide_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        sign = "/";
        val1 = double.Parse(txtbox.Text);
        txtbox.Text = "";
    }

    private void cmdsqrt_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        double v;
        v = double.Parse(txtbox.Text);
        txtbox.Text = Math.Sqrt(v).ToString();
    }

    private void cmdsquare_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        double v;
        v = double.Parse(txtbox.Text);
        txtbox.Text = Math.Pow(v,2).ToString();
    }

    private void cmdsin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        double v;
        v = double.Parse(txtbox.Text);
        txtbox.Text = Math.Sin(v).ToString();
    }

    private void cmdcos_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        double v;
        v = double.Parse(txtbox.Text);
        txtbox.Text = Math.Cos(v).ToString();
    }

    private void cmdtan_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        double v;
        v = double.Parse(txtbox.Text);
        txtbox.Text = Math.Tan(v).ToString();
    }
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
     private void txtbox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)

    {

    }
     private void txtbox_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)

    {

        int keycode;

        keycode = e.KeyChar;

        //accept only number from key 0 to key 9, key back, and key dot

        if (keycode >= 48 && keycode <= 57 || keycode==8 || keycode==32 || keycode==46)

        {

            //key dot allowed only one time

            if (keycode == 46) ++trackkeypoint;

            if (trackkeypoint > 1) { e.Handled = true; --trackkeypoint; }

        }

        else e.Handled = true;

    }



    private void txtbox_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)

    {





           }

    }
}
```

and I get this error:

[image: screenshot1]

I tried changing that to CWindowsGUI and that didn't work, or removing the offending bits, or a host of other layman fixes. It also shows up in the designer window:

[image: screenshot2]

The namespace is the same on the CWindowsGUI.Designer.cs as the actual code thing

Comment: You stated you changed something to CWindowsGUI - what did you change? The name of your Form class, the call to your form's constructor, or something else? Whenevr you changed it, clarify on "didn't work" - what error did you get?

Comment: Just a note, you could change `txtbox.Text=txtbox.Text+cmdX.Text;` to `txtbox.Text += cmdX.Text;`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at the class you provided I think you renamed your `Form1` to `Calculator`

So try:

```
Application.Run(new Calculator());
```

Edit:

CWindowsGUI.cs

```
  public partial class Calculator : Form
  {
     public Calculator() // Not public void Calculator()
     {
       InitializeComponent();
     }
```

CWindowsGUI.Designer.cs

```
  public partial class Calculator
```

Comment: I feel like an idiot, this works! Thank you so much! (Now I need to figure out why no buttons or textscreen appear) Thanks!

Comment: check that the CWindowsGUI.Designer.cs and CWindowsGUI.cs Calculator classes are both `public partial class Calculator ......`, added example to answer

Comment: try changing `public void Calculator()` to `public Calculator()`

Comment: it says, "Method must have a return type", Float or int? maybe lemme test (float or int did not work)

Comment: it has to be the name of the `Form`, this is your `Constructor` that calls `InitializeComponent();` this is what creates your controls, sounds like everything is a mess, perhaps you shold create a fresh project and copy the relevant code accross.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to fix some errors

```
 private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
```

you do not have any form named as Form1 it seems that when you created application it created a form for you named as Form1 you just renamed it from solution explorer.
delete this load event.

```
 public void Calculator()

    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
```

is it a constructor of your form **CWindowsGUI**
constructor name should be same as form name correct it.

Do You wants to run CWindowsGUI form first ???

```
Application.Run(); 

method defines that which form you wants to set as startup that's all
```

**then try this :**

```
Application.Run(new CWindowsGUI());
```

instead of

```
Application.Run(new Calculator());
```

my suggestion would be that delete this form(CWindowsGUI) and create a new form then code on that page also donot forget to change the form in

```
Application.Run(new CWindowsGUI());
```