# WindowsApplication C# constructor: Form1 could not be found

Tags: c#, initialization, exe, windows

I'm a new c# user, while creating Win-App I got error and I search here on Stackoverflow but couldn't fix my problem. I looked at [Type or namespace could not be found 'Form1'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18456242/type-or-namespace-could-not-be-found-form1)

[image: two muppets]

Error   1   *The type or namespace name **'Form1'** could not be found*

**Code:**

```
namespace WindowsApplication3
{

public partial class Form1 : Form
{

    System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient clientSocket = new System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient();

    public Form1()
    {

        InitializeComponent();

    }
```

**1.** I tried to rename my Form1 to something else but it gives me the same error.

**2.** I checked all the references and they seem to be in order.

Comment: What `namespace` is the `Program` class sat inside? Your screenshot doesn't show the `namespace` declaration around the `Program` class definition. If this was different to `WindowsApplication3` or even missing, you would get this error.

Comment: uhm No namespace, but i did try with namespace WindowsFormsApplication3, but it gives me nothing else but the same error...

Comment: Your namespace is `WindowsApplication3` not `WindowsFormsApplication3`.

Comment: @Ramiz I suspected as much, Matthew Watson's answer addresses this. The types need to either be in the same namespace, or you can reference the other namespace via a `using WindowsApplication3;` declaration at the top of the file, or you can do `Application.Run(new WindowsApplication3.Form1())`.

Comment: Application.Run(new WindowsFormsApplication3.Form1()); I just tried this but gives me exactly the same error as before.

Comment: @AlessandroD'Andria 

Problem solved "WindowsApplication3 not WindowsFormsApplication3". :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suspect a namespace error.

Is the Form in a namespace called `WindowsApplication3` and the Program class in a namespace called `WindowsFormsApplication3` by any chance?

Ensure you are using the same namespace for both, or alternatively add a `using` to Program.cs to specify the correct namespace.

Comment: Thx for answering, I am already using "using WindowsFormsApplication3;" in program.cs. I checked everywhere WindowsApplication3 = WindowsApplication3! hmm

Comment: @RamizHassan Yes but I can see from your screenshot that your `Form.cs` file is using namespace `WindowsApplication3` while your `Program.cs` file is using namespace  `WindowsFormsApplication3` - they must be the same!